# Is it possible to implement referential integrity on an intersection table so that it's parents have the same value on a foreign key column?

Tags: oracle, database-design, many-to-many, data-modeling, entity-relationship

Example Oracle SQL Code:

```
create table t1 (
        t1a integer,
        t1b varchar2(30)
);
alter table t1 add constraint t1_pk primary key (t1a);
insert into t1 values (1, 'A');
insert into t1 values (2, 'B');

create table t11 (
        t11a integer,
        t1a  integer,
        t11b varchar2(30)
);
alter table t11 add constraint t11_pk primary key (t11a);
alter table t11 add constraint t11_t1_fk foreign key (t1a) references t1(t1a);
insert into t11 values (10, 1, 'A1');
insert into t11 values (11, 2, 'B1');

create table t12 (
        t12a integer,
        t1a  integer,
        t12b varchar2(30)
);
alter table t12 add constraint t12_pk primary key (t12a);
alter table t12 add constraint t12_t1_fk foreign key (t1a) references t1(t1a);
insert into t12 values (20, 1, 'A2');
insert into t12 values (21, 2, 'B2');

create table t1112 (
        t11a integer,
        t12a integer
);
alter table t1112 add constraint t1112_pk primary key (t11a, t12a);
alter table t1112 add constraint t1112_t11_fk foreign key (t11a) references t11(t11a);
alter table t1112 add constraint t1112_t12_fk foreign key (t12a) references t12(t12a);

create or replace trigger t1112_trg before insert or update on t1112 for each row
declare
        t11a_v  integer;
        t12a_v  integer;
begin
        select t11.t1a into t11a_v from t11 where t11.t11a = :new.t11a;
        select t12.t1a into t12a_v from t12 where t12.t12a = :new.t12a;
        if (t11a_v != t12a_v) then
                raise_application_error(-20000, 'Mismatch');
        end if;
end;
/
```

Top level table: t1. 
t11 and t12 have a foreign key reference to t1.
t1112 is an intersection table between t1 and t2.
I want to ensure that any rows written into t1112 have a combination of t11 and t12 such that they both point to the same row in t1.

I have tried to implement it with a trigger in the example. Is there a way to do this via referential integrity constraints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to create additional unique constraints on tables t11 and t12:

```
ALTER TABLE t11 ADD CONSTRAINT t11_un UNIQUE ( t11a, t1a );
ALTER TABLE t12 ADD CONSTRAINT t12_un UNIQUE ( t12a, t1a );
```

Add column `t1a` to table `T1112`

```
ALTER TABLE t1112 ADD (t1a integer);
```

Drop and recreate your foreign key constraints on `t1112`:

```
ALTER TABLE T1112 DROP CONSTRAINT T1112_T11_FK;
ALTER TABLE T1112 ADD CONSTRAINT T1112_T11_FK FOREIGN KEY (t11a, t1a ) REFERENCES T11 (t11a, t1a);
ALTER TABLE T1112 DROP CONSTRAINT T1112_T12_FK;
ALTER TABLE T1112 ADD CONSTRAINT T1112_T12_FK FOREIGN KEY (t12a, t1a ) REFERENCES T12 (t12a, t1a);
```

Such that they now use the two unique constraints instead of the primary keys.  The shared column `t1a` in the join table will ensure that the keys from `t11` and `t12` join back to `t1`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a materialized view:

```sql
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW t11_t12_mv
   BUILD IMMEDIATE
   AS SELECT t11a, t12a
      FROM   t11 INNER JOIN t12 ON t11.t1a = t12.t1a;

ALTER TABLE t11_t12_mv ADD CONSTRAINT t11a_t12a__pk PRIMARY KEY ( t11a, t12a );

create table t1112 (
  t11a integer,
  t12a integer,
  CONSTRAINT t1112_pk PRIMARY KEY (t11a, t12a),
  CONSTRAINT t1112_fk FOREIGN KEY (t11a, t12a) REFERENCES t11_t12_mv ( t11a, t12a )
);
```

Then:

```sql
INSERT INTO t1112 VALUES ( 10, 20 );
INSERT INTO t1112 VALUES ( 11, 21 );
```

Works. However:

```sql
INSERT INTO t1112 VALUES ( 10, 21 );
```

Raises the exception:

> ```
> ORA-02291: integrity constraint (USER_4_F249D.T1112_FK) violated - parent key not found
> ```

*sqlfiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f249d/1)*